# Adding millions of fixed point numbers

Tags: c#, double, decimal

I have given millions of numbers with precisely 4 digits after the decimal point.

They have to be added and subtracted a lot in a complicated fashion (in an optimiziation problem). After that (and in between) I have to determine the *exact* value.

In C#, three different possibilites came to my mind:

1. Use doubles and define a rounding error for comparison.
2. Use the decimal type
3. Create a type working with integer arithmetic

What would you suggest?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the optimization problem? And what the bounds are on the numbers?  (Like, are they always less than a billion? Less than a thousand?  and so on.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely don't use `double`. It doesn't represent the information you've got.

I would personally start by using `decimal`. It's the most appropriate type for the information you've got, and you can rely on the results.

*If* that proves too slow, you could convert all the values to integers, do all the arithmetic, and then convert back - but I would only do this *after* you've seen how the `decimal` version performs.

Answer (score 3):

`double` only provides approximated representation of a decimal's fraction (e.g. there no exact binary representation of 0.2 in decimal). `decimal` type can produce an exact value throughout the arithmetics, but `decimal` can be an order slower than any base2 type such as float and double if not more.

Perhaps you can scale all number to order of 10,000 before arithmetics and operate on integers, and then place the radix back afterwards; check against decimal how it performs.